# Search terminal buffer in shell script

Tags: terminal, zsh, svn

I have a shell script named `merge` that takes a parameter that is a revision number. I usually invoke it `merge 12345`.

I would like to pass in zero parameters. The script should search my terminal output for the latest occurrence of the pattern `/^Committed revision (\d+)\.$/` and use that value. However, I don't know how to search the terminal output, or indeed whether it is possible to do so.

Comment: It's not quite searching output directly; but how about recording terminal output (say, using [`shelr`](https://github.com/antono/shelr)) and `grep`ping the newest file created by that?

Comment: That would be fine, but `shelr` in particular looks very heavyweight.

Comment: Seems like it's one command (`svn` ?) in particular you're looking for the output from. Could you alias that to `command | tee ~/commitlog.txt` and then `grep` that file?

Comment: Or if not, start your terminal session with `zsh | tee ~/teminal.log` for the whole thing (may be overkill). Or `script ~/teminal.log` for something similar; have to remember to invoke that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the phrase `Committed revision`, it appears you are using `svn`. Rather than searching your terminal output for the revision number, you can just use

```sh
svn info -r HEAD
```

to get the latest revision number at the head of your repository. But you probably don't even need the revision number: You can just use `HEAD` itself directly in whatever you're trying to do.